# can you resolve a promise in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pixi.js

I'm quite new to using promises in JS, and im trying to have a function execute before executing some more code in another function. Only issue is that the promised function uses an if statement to loop a setTimeout command. I added an if statement to make sure the function is done looping before i resolve the promise but the resolve just isn't doing anything. I used console.log to make sure that the if statement is executing and it has no problems printing to the console on either side of the resolve. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code:**

```
async makeToast(loader, toaster){
    toaster.texture = loader.resources['toaster_down'].texture;
    this.interactive = false;
    this.x = toaster.x;
    this.y = toaster.y - 100;

    let transform = {y: this.y};
    let popDown = new TWEEN.Tween(transform)
        .to({y: toaster.y - 50}, 200)
        .onUpdate(() => this.y = transform.y); 
    popDown.start();

    await this.changeTexture(loader, toaster.setting)
    console.log('toasting done');
    this.interactive = true;
}

changeTexture(loader, setting){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.state++;
            this.texture = loader.resources[`bread${this.state}`].texture;
            if(this.state < setting) this.changeTexture(loader, setting);
            else if(this.state == setting) resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: *What will resolve() do.* It is doing nothing here, just resolving the promise. Is console.log('toasting done') not printing anything?

Comment: 1. You have no `else` branch, so the condition might never attain. 2. You *say* you used `console.log`, but you have no curly braces in your conditional and you can only use a *single* statement per branch that way... 3. Every time you call the method it returns a *new* Promise, you will *never* resolve the original one.

Comment: @ikhvjs This is a SyntaxError, `await` is only valid inside `async` functions, and it won't do anything useful anyway because there is no promise being returned from inside the `new Promise` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can as long as there is a closure linking the `resolve` variable in the Promise constructor with the `resolve()` you call in your `if` statement. However in your code you don't have this:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ...

    changeTexture(loader, setting){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.state++;
                this.texture = loader.resources[`bread${this.state}`].texture;
                if(this.state < setting)
                    this.changeTexture(loader, setting); <----------.
                else if(this.state == setting)                      |
                    resolve(); <-- There is a closure to this      /
            }, 1000);                                             /
        });                          .---------------------------'
    }                                |
}                      However this function call will have it's own
                       "resolve" variable that is no longer captured
                       by this closure.
```

This means that when the `if/else` finally calls `resolve()` that resolve has nothing to do with the Promise you returned when you call `changeTexture()`.

The way to do what you want is to not call `changeTexture` recursively so that you maintain a closure between the Promise's `resolve` variable and the `resolve` you finally call. To do this simply separate your `setTimeout` callback from the main `changeTexture` function:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ...

    changeTexture(loader, setting){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let loop = () => { // use arrow function to capture "this"
                this.state++;
                this.texture = loader.resources[`bread${this.state}`].texture;
                if(this.state < setting) setTimeout(loop, 1000);
                else if(this.state == setting) resolve();
            }

            loop();
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively for minimal change in code you can get your code working by changing only one line:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ...

    changeTexture(loader, setting){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.state++;
                this.texture = loader.resources[`bread${this.state}`].texture;
                if(this.state < setting) setTimeout(arguments.callee(),1000); // <----THIS
                else if(this.state == setting) resolve();
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
}
```

The `arguments.callee` variable points to the `() => {...` function you pass to `setTimeout`. However, `arguments.callee` is deprecated and is disabled in strict mode so use the `loop` function above if possible.

Answer (score 3):

After the first `setTimeout` callback executes, you will never resolve the outermost call's returned promise. You will resolve the *innermost* call's returned promise eventually, but that does nothing since the promise returned from there is never used.

You *could* write `if (this.state < setting) resolve(this.changeTexture(loader, setting))` but I'd recommend a different, far less confusing (and non-recursive) way instead:

```js
// This could be defined globally, can be useful elsewhere too
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
```

```js
// This is in your object
async changeTexture (loader, setting) {
    while (this.state < setting) {
      await delay(1000)
      this.state++
      this.texture = loader.resources[`bread${this.state}`].texture
    }
}
```

Here I've made the `changeTexture` function `async` as well, so we can use `await` inside and therefore implement the delay in a more straight-forward manner and can build a regular `while` loop around the whole thing.

(Note: Technically your existing code does the first iteration unconditionally, so a `do ... while` would be more accurate, but I'm assuming that is just a result of the way you tried building it with `setTimeout` and not really what you need.)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `resolve` and `reject` from anywhere in your code you wish. But you *must* call exactly one of them exactly once from within your Promise.

Your sample code doesn't do that when your if-condition is false, so you need to fix that.